# How to can i do this using c++

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    string  adr="bonjour000000";
    int j=adr.length();
    cout<<adr<<"\nLa longueur de ma chaine est "<<j<<".";
    cout<<"\n";

    if(adr.length()>=7){
        //if(how to test if the characters after the 7th character are =0)
        //here begin the 2nd if loop

        for(unsigned int i=0; i<adr.length(); i++)
        {
            cout<<adr[i];
        }

        adr.erase (adr.begin()+7,adr.end());
        cout<<"\n"<<adr;

        //here ends the 2nd if loop
    }

    else{
        cout<<"Error: there is less than 7 characters";
        cout<<"\n"<<adr;
    }
}
```

I want to test first if **adr** has 7 or more than 7 characters, then I want to check if all the characters after the 7th characters are all = 0. When this is the case, I would like to cut all these 0, and when not, keep **adr** as it is.
With my example, I expected this output:

```
bonjour000000
La longueur de ma chaine est 13
bonjour000000
bonjour
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to check for the first char that is not a '0'. If there is no such character within the string bounds all of the characters are 0. You will call this on a substring that starts after char #7. You can call it with the starting position as well as @Luchian Grigore has shown

Answer (score 3):

The following:

```
bool condition = (adr.length() > 7) &&
                 (adr.find_first_not_of('0', 7) == std::string::npos);
```

Comment: What is the use of npos here please? Does it give me the position of the first non-zero character or something else? And if I use this bool condition, does it also walk if there is a 0 between the first 7th character? In this case, it will not be a problem, then I need in every time to keep the 7 first character equal which type, these will be belong

Comment: @FrankyN. It's the value returned by a find function if the character or substring was not found. That function is looking for the first character that is not `'0'`, if there are no characters that are not `'0'` (i.e. all characters after the 7th are `'0'`), it will return `std::npos`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore  Sorry, I just starting to use c++ and I don't know how to adapt this to my problem.

Comment: @FrankyN. first thing you can do is google whatever keywords you don't understand.

Comment: I tried tp use your solution, but I receive this as error ** 'npos' is not a member of 'std'|main.cpp|13|warning: unused variable 'npos'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 2 warnings ===|
** May I use string::npos or std::npos?

Comment: @FrankyN. ah, my bad, it's `std::string::npos`.

Comment: I google about the function **find_first_not_of**, but I don't find anything interrsting for me. I don't need to return the position of the first zero-character after the 7th character, but I want to erase all zero character and I don't know how to use the solution you proposed to me.